# Kafka My producer works topic is Par: 0 ,Lead:1, Rep:1, Isr:1 BUT NOT Par: 0 ,Lead:2, Rep:2, Isr:2

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a kakfa cluster with 3 kafka nodes and 3 zk nodes.

The producer is on AWS machine trying to push data on my kafka cluster running on my intranet servers.

When the topic (JOB_AWS_14) is created from console with

```
Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
```

it works fine.

But where a topic(JOB_AWS_8)  is created with

```
Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
```

it is not working.

What settings went wrong and how to correct it.

Please help me.

```
# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic JOB_AWS_14
Topic:JOB_AWS_14        PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: JOB_AWS_14       Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1

# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic JOB_AWS_8
Topic:JOB_AWS_8 PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: JOB_AWS_8        Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
```

Comment: as you see here, your second topic has still one partiton. Topic:JOB_AWS_8 PartitionCount:1

Answer (score 0):

Your producer is reachable to Kafka node-1 which is leader for topic "JOB_AWS_14" so you are able to produce messages to that topic while coming to topic "JOB_AWS_8" leader is Kafka node-2 and your producer might not be reachable to Node-2. Make sure your producer is reachable to node-2.